# Transposing Data in Excel and Matching With a Unique ID

Tags: excel, aggregate, transpose

The first Excel file contains item analysis data for each student in the class:

```
Student ID    Item #    Response
101           1         A
101           2         B
101           3         D
101           4         B
```

Granted, this is just an excerpt of a file that has 500 unique student IDs.

In the second Excel file, I have the final grades for each student:

```
Student ID    Grade    
101           95         
102           87        
103           65         
104           72
```

Again, this second Excel file has 500 unique student IDs.  I need to make a file that essentially looks like the second Excel file, where each row represents a unique student ID and each column represents each test item and the final grade.  How can I do this without resorting to copy and transpose paste?

Answer (score 0):

On your final grade file, add columns for each item #. Assuming the first item # is in cell C2, and your item analysis data is in sheet Sheet1, put the following formula in cell C2 of your grade file, validate with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (it's an array formula), then copy across and down.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5000,MATCH($A2&"|"&C$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5000&"|"&Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5000,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is with 2 steps.
First you have to change the grade letters to numbers(for Excel t make an average on the 2nd step)
[image]

I took an example of grades but you can change it as you desire.

To switch the grades use the `vlookup` function. lets assume your first 3 coulmns are occupied with: Student ID    Item #    Response  and your grade table is on columns e and F then on cell d2 insert the following :

```
=vlookup(a2,e:f,2,0)
```

Now you are ready to make an average of each student. the best way to to so is by a Pivot table. Choose all of the data and click on the insert ribbon to insert a pivot table. on rows get drag the students. and columns drag the fixed grade(numbers) the only thing left to to is to change the value from count to average.